# Manual mock of object in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to figure out manual mocks in Jest. I think this should be easy...but it isn't.

My project directories are like

- __tests__

  - user-test.js
- models

  - user.js
  - __mocks__

    - user.js
- node_modules

  - ...
- package.json

Both models/user.js and models/__mocks__/user.js have the same code:

```
module.exports = {
    create(username, password) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve({"username":username, "password": password});
            }, 100);
        });
    }
}
```

The file __tests__/user-test.js looks like this:

```
test('user creation works', () => {
    const user = require('../models/user');
    //const user = jest.mock('../models/user');
    return user.create("mitchell", "boo");
});
```

This works fine, tests pass, but when I change it to:

```
test('user creation works', () => {
    //const user = require('../models/user');
    const user = jest.mock('../models/user');
    return user.create("mitchell", "boo");
});
```

It doesn't work, and spits out:

```
 FAIL  __tests__\user-test.js
  ● user creation works

    TypeError: user.create is not a function

      at Object.<anonymous>.test (__tests__\user-test.js:4:17)
      at process._tickCallback (internal\process\next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Answer (score 27):

Ah! Figured it out! My folder structure is fine. Turns out I had a misunderstanding as to what "jest.mock" actually did. "jest.mock" changes the behavior of the node "require" function to use the mock, it doesn't do a require itself.

My test should have looked like:

```
jest.mock('../models/user');
test('user creation works', () => {
    const user = require('../models/user');
    return user.create("mitchell", "boo");
});
```

Comment: Jest mock is used to prevent the functions in a module to be called when module is initialized or an object is instantiated, It is made this way to provide a good shield against other software layers that are not the target of the current unit test